# non blocking read from pipe with c++ stdlib

Tags: c++, c++17, posix, nonblocking

In 2021, is there a way to do a non blocking read from a pipe, using the high-level tools of the C++ standard library? I.e. C++17 (or maybe C++20)? Developing on Linux, but some degree of portability to other *NIX would be desirable. *Boost is not an option for my problem at hand.*

I know the POSIX functions well, i.e. `poll()` and `open()` with `O_NONBLOCK`. Following that route, I'd implement my own buffering and splitting into lines and moreover that data is binary (which in fact is not so much of a problem as it might seem, as long as it's unicode-utf8 and basically just passed through into some report, where other existing software will do the proper rendering of characters, e.g. Markdown to HTML).

Just I'm asking myself, do I really have to implement that (again)? Or is there some ready made solution available, which I'm just overlooking? To my understanding, the `std::basic_istream<..>` is not a good fit, since it attempts to fill the underlying buffer and will block when not enough data is in the pipe.

*For Background:* I am retrieving STDIN and STDERR from a subprocess through two pipes. I have to interleave those two streams on a line by line base. This happens within a dedicated reader thread ― however, this reader thread must not get stuck, even if the subprocess goes into a live lock.

Comment: C++20 coroutines should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ library has no concepts of "pipes" or other operating system-specific resources.

> For Background: I am retrieving STDIN and STDERR from a subprocess
> through two pipes. I have to interleave those two streams on a line by
> line base.

What I would do for this case: subclass `std::streambuf` and override `underflow()`. The overridden `underflow()` implements non-blocking reads from both pipes, separately, keeping separate buffers for each pipe. And `std::streambuf`'s buffer gets filled with a completed line from whichever pipe a completed line managed to be read from, first, as soon as there is one.

There's an overloaded `std::istream` constructor that takes a pointer to a custom `std::streambuf` parameter.

You end up with what looks like a plain, garden-variety, `std::istream` that you can `std::getline` and get whichever pipe managed to produce a complete line, ending up with line-by-line interleaved input.

Answer (score 0):

Spawn two `std::thread` each reading from different pipe. Reading `std::getline` to a separate `std::string`. After reading a line put the `std::string` to a `std::vector<std::string>` protected by `std::mutex`, and then notify a `condition_variable`. In the main thread, you can wait on a `condition_variable` for new events, then grab the `mutex` and flush all lines from `std::vector<std::string>` to output.

Like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <fstream>
#include <assert.h>

std::mutex g_lines_mutex;
std::condition_variable g_lines_notify;
std::vector<std::string> g_lines;

void outputter() {
    while (1) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(g_lines_mutex);
        if (g_lines.empty()) {
             g_lines_notify.wait(guard);
        }
        for (auto&& i : g_lines) {
            std::cout << "Read line: " << i << "\n";
        }
        g_lines.clear();
    }
}

void interleaver(const char *arg) {
    std::ifstream f(arg);
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(f, line)) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(g_lines_mutex);
            g_lines.emplace_back(std::move(line));
        }
        g_lines_notify.notify_one();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    assert(argc == 3);
    std::array<std::thread, 3> t = {
        std::thread{ outputter },
        std::thread{ interleaver, argv[1] },
        std::thread{ interleaver, argv[2] },
    };
    for (auto&& i : t) {
        i.join();
    }
}
```

Then such program compiled and run with:

```
$ mkfifo fifo1 fifo2; 
$ ( exec 3> fifo1 ; exec 4> fifo2; while sleep 1; do echo 1 $(date) >&3 ; echo 2 $(date) >&4; done; ) &
$ g++ -pthread ./1.cpp && ./a.out fifo1 fifo2
Read line: 1 Sun, 01 Aug 2021 17:41:25 +0200
Read line: 2 Sun, 01 Aug 2021 17:41:25 +0200
Read line: 1 Sun, 01 Aug 2021 17:41:26 +0200
Read line: 2 Sun, 01 Aug 2021 17:41:26 +0200
Read line: 1 Sun, 01 Aug 2021 17:41:27 +0200
Read line: 2 Sun, 01 Aug 2021 17:41:27 +0200
```

Comment: Some people, when faced with an I/O-bound problem will say "I'll use threads!". Now they have 3 problems.

Comment: @KamilCuk this proposed solution has indeed the benefit of *just using* C++ building blocks, and it is quite compact and easy to understand.

I have two objections though: (1) a mutex for each and every line can be quite heavy, esp. when the output is massive. (2) when the child livelocks, the join will block; thus we'd have to detect that separately and kill the child or detach() the interleaver threads